# Log4j2 logfile not getting generated after changing name pattern

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I am trying to create logfiles with dynamic names that include the date they were generated.

I have the following log4j2.properties file:

```
status = error
name = PropertiesConfig
 
property.filename = C:\\logs\\debug.log
 
filters = threshold
 
filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
filter.threshold.level = debug
 
appenders = rolling
 
appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
appender.rolling.fileName = ${filename}
appender.rolling.filePattern = debug-backup-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size=10MB
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.max = 20
 
loggers = rolling
 
logger.rolling.name = com.howtodoinjava
logger.rolling.level = debug
logger.rolling.additivity = false
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile
```

However, I do not want to have the hours, minutes and seconds in the filename, so I changed the `appender.rolling.filePattern` property to `debug-backup-%d{MM-dd-yy}-%i.log` and the file stopped generating. I tried different date formats as well, but no matter how I changed it, it would no longer work, unless I undo and use the old date format.

Answer (score 0):

change date format in the property to %d{yyyy-MM-dd}
Another point to note is file roll over will happen when date changes, so file with this date will not created immediately, it creates when date changes.

easy way to test is to change the value of rolling file size to 1 MB and check if backup file is getting created with expected file name